# Expression in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this simple code:

```
    currentDataTable.Columns.Add("Active", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    currentDataTable.Columns.Add("Symbol", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    currentDataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {currentDataTable.Columns[1]};

    string FilterExpression = "Symbol = AAA";
    DataRow[] existingRows = currentDataTable.Select(FilterExpression);
```

When executing, I get this error: Cannot find column [AAA].

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want "AAA" to be interpreted as a string, use:

```
string FilterExpression = "Symbol = 'AAA'";
```

From the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) documentation:

> When you create an expression for a
>   filter, enclose strings with single
>   quotation marks: